# How to pass argument through signal and slots?

Tags: qt

My GUI consists of a **LineEdit** and a **PushButton**. When the **PushButton** is clicked, the slot `clicked()` is called. I want to setup a signal-slot relationship between `clicked()` as the signal and `doSomething()` as the slot. The issue is that `doSomething()` does not have access to the UI and `doSomething()` relies on the text of **LineEdit** to work.

I see two solutions:

1. Grant doSomething() access to the UI.
2. I want to be able to pass a QString to doSomething() as an argument. clicked() does not accept any arguments. Qsignalmapper might be what I'm looking for. However, it seems like the mapper only passes arguments based on what the signal is. The arguments therefore need to be setup in advance and it seems like it does not help me here.

How would I do solution 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a C++ solution, you might consider using an intermediate signal like the following for #2:

```
connect(thisWidget, SIGNAL(clicked()),
        thisWidget, SLOT(slotClickHandler()));
```

then:

```
void slotClickHandler()
{
   QString s = "my variable string here";

  emit sigDoSomething(s);
}
```

and them:

```
void slotDoSomething(const QString &s)
{
   // Do something interesting with s here

}
```

Note that this snippet assumes you've defined a new signal `sigDoSomething(const QString &)` and a private slot `void slotDoSomething(const QString &)`.

Comment: Brilliant! Which would you say is cleaner? Method 1 or method 2? It depends, right? The problem with method 2 is duplicating the number of signals/slots can get messy when you're dealing with a lot of GUI elements, correct? Also, why is it const QString &s? Shouldn't it just be QString s?

Comment: As you state, which is "cleaner" depends.  What does cleaner mean? Easier to read? Easier to debug? Easier on the compiler? The developer is usually the weakest link, so bias "cleaner" accordingly.  Map signals and slots clearly to their respective widgets (with meaningful names, etc.).  Let the QT moc and gcc  worry about the number of calls.  Simple chained function calls will likely be optimized anyway.  Lastly, the seeming duplication of calls will be dependent on your implementation: how many pushbuttons are there? what exactly do they need to convey>?, etc.

Comment: As for const QString &, I'm assuming that the slot implementation does not need to modify the QString s.  If so, a pass-by-value (i.e. QString s), will make a needless copy of the QString object.  On the other hand, passing the QString by reference (QString &) allows the compiler to pass a more efficient reference (in essence a pointer to the object).  Adding the const qualifier assures that the compiler is aware that the QString is not expected to be modified.  (Indeed, the compiler will assert an error if you attempt to modify a const object).

Comment: If you wish the slot to modify the QString, then you probably need to rethink the design.  Nasty issues can arise.